# Continuous $L^2$ function has finite sum at integer points?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)|^2$ is finite?

If the continuity condition is dropped, the statement is not true, because $f(n)$ could have very high values only at the integer points.

Comment: No. Construct a piecewise linear function that's $1$ at every integer, but has slope $n^4$ going up and down from each one. Your sum will be infinite, but its square-integral will be finite.

Comment: @Mike You're right. Maybe this one is what I should ask as well: please see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594922/sum-of-squares-at-integer-points-for-l2-function)