# Sum of squares at integer points for $L^2$ function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |f(n)|^2$ is finite?

If the continuity and going to zero conditions are dropped, the statement is not true, because $f(n)$ could have very high values only at the integer points.

Comment: I think this one fails too. Make the integers have $f(n) \frac 1 {\sqrt{|n|}}$, and give them that same slope $n^4$ - again, it's definitely square-integrable, but the sum of squares is the harmonic series.

Comment: @Mike Hmm okay.. is there any hope of making this kind of statement true if we impose some conditions?

Comment: I honestly don't know - infinitely differentiable doesn't work, since we can just get a smooth function that's really close to the one I've given you there. That would be an interesting question - I encourage you to post a question asking about conditions that would imply your sums-of-squares thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is that functions in $L_{p}(\mathbb{R})$ are not necessarily bounded. Consider the function
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} n2^{n}\left(x - n + \frac{1}{2^{n}} \right)& \textrm{if } x \in \left[ n - \frac{1}{2^{n}}, n\right]\\[0.5em]
n2^{n}\left(n + \frac{1}{2^{n}} - x \right) & \textrm{if } x \in \left[ n, n + \frac{1}{2^{n}}\right]\\[0.5em] 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
which is basically a piecewise continuous function with thiner and thiner triangles around $n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. One can show that this function $f \in L_{p}(\mathbb{R})$ for $p \in [1,\infty)$.

However, $\forall n\ \ f(n) = n$.

Comment: This isn't a counterexample to the question as stated, since it assumed $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. But $f(x)/(1+|x\ln x|)$ works.

Answer (score 0):

This has been considered to death in the context of the [Poisson summation formula.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula) See the linked to wiki article and references there in (and/or google Poisson summation).